# How to sell a technical training course online

Tags: training

I have worked as a technical trainer and had made several technical trainings during that period. I wanted to know the following:

1. I have theory modules (in ppt format) and practical modules (programming codes) of a training available with me. I used it to deliver instructor led training program. How can I modify them into online training program?
2. How can I sell them to learners for a small fee ? Once I know how to do so, I can make several other training programs as a Freelance Training Content Developer and retail them online.

Looking forward to some expert freelancing guidance.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few tips. I hope they can help:

1. Create video content from existing ppt slides and code.
2. Try to create complete courses including lectures and development exercises.
3. You should go for Udemy, as it can help you alot. You can create courses there and sell them at good prices.
4. Write development code at runtime so that the viewers can see
   development in front of them and it can help them learn more.

I hope these help. Feel free to ask if you have any queries!

Answer (score 0):

I hope Udemy site can help you. (https://www.udemy.com/teaching/?ref=teach_header). This is one of the reputed online training platform. The link will help you the plan to become tutor and their plans for charging fees.